# All Openoffice Document words to Uppercase using basic

Tags: openoffice.org

Let be

> text msklakkdkdkdklalksksla

an openoffice document

How I can convert all strings of an openoffice document to Uppercase strings using openoffice basic (programing language similiar to visual basic) without change the styles?

Someone suggest:

```
ThisComponent.Text.setString( UCase(ThisComponent.Text.String) )
```

Comment: And he is correct. This command wrapped in a macro form will solve your problem.

Comment: @Epaminondas What's a command?

Answer (score 0):

There are many excellent tutorials in writing a macro in OpenOffice / LibreOffice while probably the most complete book is [OpenOffice.org Macros Explained](http://www.pitonyak.org/OOME_3_0.odt) by Andrew D. Pitonyak.

Now, assuming you use LibreOffice:

1. Open LibreOffice Writer and write something in the blank document.
2. Select from the menu: *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic*.
3. Select the macro with the name *Main* and press the button **Edit**.
4. Normally the syntax editor of the LibreOffice Basic will appear and you will see the lines

   ```
   Sub Main
   End Sub
   ```
5. Put the line

   ```
   ThisComponent.Text.setString( UCase(ThisComponent.Text.String) )
   ```

between Sub Main and End Sub.

6. Close the LibreOffice Basic Editor.
7. Select again from the menu: *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic*
8. Select the macro with the name *Main* and now press the button **Run**.

Normally all text in your document is now uppercase.